# Small changes to code completely alters the WindowBuilder design

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

Changes I am making in my sourcecode are completely screwing up the way WindowBuilder interprets it. In other words, the changes in my code are either not reflecting properly in the WindowBuilder or reflecting when no changes to layout or graphics have been made.

This is what my login window looks like when run - and USED to look like in design view (I removed the company logo in the upper part for this question as it's confidential)
[image: Login Window design]

However, in the Window Builder Design View now, it looks like this:
(I didn't even cover up the logo - it just doesn't appear)
[image: Design View mess up]

In terms of changes to the code:

- I moved JFrame to a superclass from the class itself (should make no difference)
- Moved the declaration of JButtons outside the `initialize()` method to the global scope of the class.
- Added some listeners to the buttons via
- a controller class object that I passed when called
- I did not remove or alter the `main` method of the WindowBuilder template.

Does anyone know what these problems are coming from?

Comment: Learn Swing. WindowBuilder is very, very, very, very, very buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer to my own question:

I've found that one of my main problems is that I moved the `JFrame` out from the class itself into a superclass that generalizes a few views. This was causing a problem with the WindowBuilder parser.

Just putting that out there in case someone is having the same issue...